# Use text with eval in hyperlink

Tags: c#, hyperlink

I have a hyperlink whose navigate url is supposed to get `http://www.google.com`.
My Eval returns `www.google.com` so i tried this.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl=' "http://" + <%#Eval("osite")%>' runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("osite")%>' > </asp:HyperLink>
```

It wont work

Comment: Do you need this to be a server control? If you just need a link, just use a regular `<a>` tag instead of using an ASP.NET `HyperLink` control.

Comment: try to put url in a property in codebehind, and use that property on design page. Hope this work, right now i can't test it.

Comment: It will be more complex as the hyperlink is inside a nested datalist

Comment: @JoeEnos `<a href='<%#Eval("osite")%>' runat="server" >  <%#Eval("osite")%> </a>` this shows the link but wont work

Comment: Take out the `runat="server"` part - that's what makes it a server control. Without that, you're just writing raw HTML, and can put whatever you want in it.